# Source files with `*.in` extension

Tags: compiling, source

When poking around in some source code trees, sometimes I encounter files with extension "*.in", typically for non-compiled files that belong somewhere under /etc or /usr/share.

For example, in [openwsman](https://github.com/Openwsman/openwsman) source code, I can see file:

```
etc/owsmangencert.sh.in
```

which by content corresponds to

```
/etc/openwsman/owsmangencert.sh
```

when deployed from RPM (RHEL7), save for some variable references.

I assume files like this are used in building process to finally appear in the mentioned path.  But why are they named `originalname.in` instead of `originalname`?  What usually happens with files like this before they land?

How are such files called?   Can anybody point me to the right documents?

Note that Openwsman also has etc/owsmangencert.sh.cmake, which is similar case.

Comment: Those are input for `pkgconfig`.

Comment: `.in` just stands for input, as in input files. A common place to find them in the context of autotools - autoconf, automake, libtool. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system. These files, at least in the autotools setting, are typically templates of some kind that are transformed by some procedure to produce a final version of the file.

Comment: They're just templated/parameterized versions of a file that will get generated during compilation/build time.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, there is no single program that is meant to use use `.in`
files, but using the suffix `.in` does hint at the fact that it's not the
final file. Instead, the `.in` file will serve as a kind of template or input
to generate the file with the same name but without the `.in` suffix.

In the case of openwsman, an example you'll often find in packages that
you can compile from source, is the `configure.in` file. This is processed
by autoconf/automake and results in a file called `configure`. This new
version is an actual shell script that you can execute on the command line.

In turn, the `configure` script itself can also process certain `.in` files.
As an example, take the file called `openwsman.pc.in`. There, you'll see
lines like

```
Version: @VERSION@
```

The thing between the `@` symbols is a variable used by the configure
script. In the resulting openwsman.pc.in` the value of this variable 
will be filled in, for example:

```
Version: 2.4.5
```

This `@(variablename)@` syntax is also recognized by the CMake build system.
So running CMake will also transform the `openwsman.pc.in` file to `openwsman.pc`.
It does this because of the following line in the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openwsman.pc.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/openwsman.pc)
```

The `etc/owsmangencert.sh.cmake` is transformed in the same way, but based
on the extension I would assume that only the CMake build system does this
and not the configure script. In this case, the relevant line is found in
the `etc/CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/owsmangencert.sh.cmake ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/owsmangencert.sh)
```

So in conclusion, there's no one single piece of documentation that explains this,
but it's often used in build scripts like configure scripts or CMakeLists.txt files
from CMake.

Answer (score 0):

There files are templates, take look inside [owsmangencert.sh.in](https://github.com/Openwsman/openwsman/blob/master/etc/owsmangencert.sh.in)

```
CERTFILE=@SYSCONFDIR@/servercert.pem
KEYFILE=@SYSCONFDIR@/serverkey.pem
CNFFILE=@SYSCONFDIR@/ssleay.cnf
```

*@SYSCONFDIR@* will be replaced actual path

After automake's configure, will be config.status generated, which will replace tokens with actual values, during make process.
So thats automake templates. For [deeper](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html) knowledge.

Comment: @brm explained that better

Answer (score 0):

the only *.in files I have come across are config.in for specifying .configure steps with autoconf and automake.

In this sense the *.in is a variables file. It keeps your script clean of variables, so you can have edit access to a variables file and run access on the script but not edit access on the script.